# Scanner with just a File VS Scanner with FileReader and File

Tags: java, file, filereader

Guys i'm just wandering what is the difference between these lines

1. `Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));`
2. `Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filePath));`
3. `Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader(filePath));`

is their any kind of instance when you will use them? or their all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all identical.  The `File` constructors are for convenience.  Sometimes you will get other `Readers` (not from a File) or need to construct the `FileReader` yourself (in order to specify an encoding) in which case the `Reader` constructor is important.